# Is there a way to set a Button to always be the front object so as to receive input?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My Button always draws on the top since its zposition is set the highest.

But as other views move around near it sometimes they other views seem to be blocking the input going to the button even though it's on top of the z-order.

Is there some kind of setting or flag that I have missed that you are supposed to set to allow buttons to not get blocked from the input, to always be the top object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you've written the button as your own sub-class of any UIResponder class then you can override the method

```
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
```

as long as it returns false, the button will remain first responder.

If that behavior isn't desired, then you could instead set userInteractionEnabled to NO on the other views that are blocking input to your button

Comment: Well Button is always on screen.It is small and in the corner. It slighty over laps with another item than can take user input. Its need to always be enabled so that the user can be navigate to the previous screen. But the other objects also have user interaction so i cannot just disable user interaction for them. I'm guessing there is no elegant solution for this so?